# Can I find the Sorting key/OrderBy key or other creation time properties of already created Table in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Can I find the Sorting key i.e. Order BY key or Primary Key used at a time of Table creation in Clickhouse?
Same goes for if I want to find the Table Engine used for creation, How can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `system.tables`

```sql
SELECT
    sorting_key,
    engine_full
FROM system.tables
WHERE (database = '<database_name>') AND (name = '<table_name>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found with the help of another answer.
You can use the command

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE db.table ;
```

which outputs something like

```
│ CREATE TABLE db.table
(
    `field1` Int64,
    `field2` Int64,
    `field3` DateTime,
    
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(field3)
PRIMARY KEY field1
ORDER BY (field1)
SETTINGS xxxx │
```

which results in showing the command used at the time of table creation.